# Riverpod StateProvider doesn't work on list

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying to create a Checkbox List, `selectedProvider` contains a boolean list with length `choices.lenght`. Let's say `choices.length` is 4, the initial list should be `[false, false, false, false]`, let's say the user click on the last one, the list should turned into `[false, false, false, true]`, but the bullet box doesn't update. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Widget getCheckboxList(WidgetRef ref, int start, int end) {
  List<Widget> content = [];

  final selectedProvider = StateProvider<List<bool>>(
      (ref) => List.filled(choices.length, false));

  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    content.add(
      Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: -2, vertical: -2),
          title: Row(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text(choices[i][0]),
              const Spacer(),
              Text(choices[i][1] == 0 ? '免費' : '+ HK\$ ${choices[i][1]}'),
              const SizedBox(width: 16),
            ],
          ),
          activeColor: primaryColor,
          value:
              ref.watch(selectedProvider.select((selected) => selected[i])),
          onChanged: (bool? picked) {
            ref.read(selectedProvider.notifier).state[i] = picked!;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  return Column(children: [...content]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the state is immutable, we need to do something like this:

```
onChanged: (_) {
  ref.read(selectedProvider.notifier).update(
        (state) => [
          for (var j = 0; j < state.length; j++)
            if (j == i) !state[j] else state[j],
        ],
      );
},
```

It will be more readable if you use `StateNotifier` and `StateNotifierProvider` instead. You can then define a `toggle()` function.

```
class Selected extends StateNotifier<List> {
  Selected(List initial) : super(initial);

  void toggle(index) {
    state = [
      for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++)
        if (i == index) !state[i] else state[i],
    ];
  }
}
```

Then define the provider

```
final selectedProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Selected, List>(
    (ref) => Selected(List.filled(8, false)));
```

When you have to change the value,

```
onChanged: (_) {
  ref.read(selectedProvider.notifier).toggle(i);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you've put the provider definition inside the `getCheckboxList` method, which I would presume (without seeing the rest of the code) that it is used inside another widget's `build` method. That will cause the method to be recalled (and re-executed) each time the widget rebuilds.

If you move the `selectedProvider` definition to outside of any class (as is required), it should work for you.

In general, you should avoid using methods for building widgets. These are highly inefficient, and do not get "cached" by the platform when the app runs. Instead, you can (and should) package such logic inside custom widgets.

For example, the above might be changed into this:

```dart
// content_widget.dart
final selectedProvider = StateProvider<List<bool>>(
  (ref) => List.filled(4, false),
);

class ContentWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext build, WidgetRef ref) {
    final List<bool> selectedValues = ref.watch(selectedProvider);

    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(),
      child: Column(
        ...
        children: List.generate(
          selectedValues.length,
          (int i) => CheckboxListTile(
            ...
            value: selectedValues[i],
            onChanged: (bool? selected) {
              ref.read(selectedProvider.notifier).state[i] = picked!;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And if you want your provider to change its size based on an arbitrary `choices` object, you can simply create a `choicesProvider` and then your `selectProvider` can use it like this:

```dart
final selectedProvider = StateProvider<List<bool>>(
  (ref) => List.filled(ref.watch(choicesProvider).length, false),
);
```

Comment: Hm... I moved the `selectedProvider` outside of any class, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with the updated code...?